# How can I set the "fat" option to true in Unison GTK?

Tags: unison

Is it possible to set the "fat" option to true using the Unison GTK interface?

[image: Unison]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, I just tested it using Ubuntu 16.04 and Unison 2.48.3.

There are two ways you can do that:

- When you start Unison GTK, the Profile Selection window is displayed. You can click on the *Add* button, this starts the Profile Creation wizard.

  - The first screen allows you to type a profile name and description.
  - The second screen allows you to select the kind of synchronization that is to be performed (*Local* in your case).
  - The third screen allows you to select the two directories that are to be synchronized (for example, your Documents directory and a directory on an external hard drive).
  - The fourth screen specifically allows you to set the *fat* option for your new profile.
  - (The fifth screen allows you to save your new profile.)
- When you already have an existing profile, you can simply click on it, and then click the *Edit* button. This will list the preferences that are already set in the profile.

  - In that list, you can click the *Add* button to show the list of available preferences.
  - Select *fat* from the list, click the *Add* button at the bottom of the window.
  - In the *Edit the Preference* window that pops up, choose *True* for the value of the *fat* option, and click the *OK* button.
  - You are back to the Profile Editor, where the *fat* preference is now listed. Click the *OK* button to save the profile.